# Insert rows in an empty data extension on salesforce marketing cloud by using API call

Tags: api, url, postman, data-extraction, salesforce-marketing-cloud

I didn't achieve to receive data in my data extension (empty) by using the API multiple data extension rows method.

I created a data extension with 7 variables (6 data type = text, 1 is a date). One of the 7 variables is a primary key (text data type).

On postman, I created a first POST request:

1. URL: `https://mc08wx0hkc21mnr8g402m7q36hy4.auth.marketingcloudapis.com/v2/token`
2. In the body:

   ```
   { 
       "client_id": " ", 
       "client_secret": " ", 
       "account_id": " ", 
       "grant_type": " " 
   }
   ```

With all the information about the package that I created on marketing cloud and that I have to use:

```
(scope : data extension => read, write)
```

By sending this request, I got my `access_token`.

The second part is more confused for me, I have to make the connection so as to populate my data extension.

I created a second POST request:

1. In the body:

   ```
   Host : https://MY_SUBDOMAIN.rest.marketingcloudapis.com
   POST /hub/v1/dataevents/key: ID DataExtension/rowset
   Content-Type: application/json
   Authorization: Bearer eyJhY2Nlc...
   ```

The part with the URL is more confused for me. As I said before, I have one primary key in the data extension that I created to receive the datas

2. URL: `https://mc08wx0hkc21mnr8g402m7q36hy4.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/ POST /hub/v1/dataevents/key: EXTERNAL_KEY_OF_MY_DATA_EXTENSION/keys :MY_PRIMARY_KEY_NAME/`

I followed the [Salesforce](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/postDataExtensionRowsetByKey.html) docs.

By sending the request, I had:

```
<h1>596 Service Not Found</h1>
```

Comment: Have you looked at the official [SFMC Postman collection](https://www.postman.com/salesforce-developers/workspace/salesforce-developers/documentation/14448118-2835a976-010c-4548-92f8-f42c0382758e)?

Comment: hello, i just checked and i found a case close of mine : Salesforce Marketing Cloud APIs > Messaging & Journeys > REST > Data Events > Synchronous > Upsert Row Set - DE Key. I wrote the same URL with my subdomain and the external key of my data extension. As i saw here : "https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/postDataExtensionRowsetByKey.html", i wrote the first exemple of the request because i "don't know" what is going to be put in the data extension.

Comment: YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN : i wrote the token that i had with the first POST request. A the end i had : {"documentation":"https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/error-handling.htm","errorcode":0,"message":"Bad Request"}